# Integrate a library inside a library as .aar in .aar

Tags: android, frameworks, lib

I am trying to integrate a custom library inside another custom library, both in .aar format. I have build both as Android library projects and I am trying to use one inside the other. I am getting a ClassNotFound exception when I am trying to access the other class from the other . I am recieving a Runtime exception and the code is compiling fine for me.

Comment: Can you please show use some code of what you have been trying.

Comment: I am afraid I wouldn't be able to share the code in the forum but here is brief description of what the issue is, I have a two libraries which are compile in .aar format and I have a method getA() in the first library which I am using inside a function getB() inside the second framework . Now I am using the second framework inside a project and trying to use the function getB() inside the project and I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for this

Comment: We can't help you much I we can't see where is the problem coming from